# Use of undefined constant PHP ver 7.2

Tags: php, php-7.2

It looks like there are quite some posts on this topic, however this case seems to be different.

In PHP version greater than or equal to 7.2 the following code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['rxdebug']) || AH_DEBUG){
    define(AH_DEBUG_MODE, true);
}else{
    define(AH_DEBUG_MODE, false);
}
```

Will throw an error on second define line `define(AH_DEBUG_MODE, false);`

```
Use of undefined constant AH_DEBUG_MODE- assumed 'AH_DEBUG_MODE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in some-file.php on line xxx
```

Basically the first define is accepted, the second one no....Isn't the code processed one time only? Or does a sort of pre-processor run beforehand throwing the error as if the constant is defined twice?

Comment: There should be quotes around constant name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
define('AH_DEBUG_MODE', true);
```

Having: `define(AH_DEBUG_MODE, true)` you force PHP to evaluate the value of a constant `AH_DEBUG_MODE` which is obviously not defined yet.

Your code can be simplified to:

```
define('AH_DEBUG_MODE', !empty($_GET['rxdebug']) || AH_DEBUG);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, why does this occur only on second definition?

Comment: Because the `!empty($_GET['rxdebug']) || AH_DEBUG` evaluates to `false` so the `else` statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be wrapping the constant's name in quotes. Check the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

```
if (!empty($_GET['rxdebug']) || AH_DEBUG){
    define('AH_DEBUG_MODE', true);
}else{
    define('AH_DEBUG_MODE', false);
}
```